# Error (404) on loading visualization api with package using google-js-api in Polymer app

Tags: google-visualization, polymer-1.0

I have a problem with my Polymer app when i'm trying to load the visualuization api for google charts

There is my component code:

```
<dom-module id="reports">
  <style>
     :host {
        display: block;
      }
  </style>
  <template>
    <google-js-api id="jsApi"></google-js-api>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function () {
      Polymer({
        is: 'reports',

        properties: {
          api: Object
        },

        listeners: {
          'jsApi.js-api-load': 'jsApiLoaded'
        },

        jsApiLoaded: function(e) {

          this.set('api', this.$.jsApi.api );
          this.api.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});
        }


    });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Initially js api is loaded and i can call method 'load', but then it getting this 404 OK response when it call the the url:

[https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.ru.8ZYSBLetUX0.O/m=visualization/exm=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCMMJjp4DU5-D3MjYkKcag3KjkzHIQ/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_2](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.ru.8ZYSBLetUX0.O/m=visualization/exm=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCMMJjp4DU5-D3MjYkKcag3KjkzHIQ/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_2)

From the beginning I need to use this library to build the page in my app with few [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls?hl=en) and I forced to try to use this js api because the native Polymer google chart doesn't have the filtering option. 
If somebody already had the same goals - please give an advice about how to do it better with polymer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note: your element name [must contain a dash](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#register-element).

Comment: Check your URL. I'm getting a 404 when I try to get that page.